# How to validate a date field in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to validate the field so that cannot be greater than today's date. I tried it like this but i dont know how to call this function to validate the date:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod( "greaterThan", function( value, element ) { 

    var now=new Date(); 

    if ( !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)) ) { 

        return new Date(value) > now; 

    } 

    return isNaN(value) || (parseFloat(value) > now); 

}, 
'should not be greater than {0}.' );
```

Comment: what are our limitations on solution?

Comment: What format is the date in?  Unix Timestamp?  array of day,month,year?  ...??

Comment: I am new to jquery.I  tried it like this but i dont know how to call this function to validate the date:jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function(value, element) {
        var now=new Date();
 if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
                return new Date(value) > now;
            }
            return isNaN(value)  || (parseFloat(value) > now); 
        },'should not be greater than {0}.');

Comment: You should be able to add the class `greaterThan` to a form input to validate using this rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple rule by doing something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanToday", function(value, element) {
    var now=new Date(); 
    if ( !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)) ) { 
        return new Date(value) > now; 
    } 
    return isNaN(value) || (parseFloat(value) > now); 
}, "* The date should not be greater than today.");
```

And then applying this like so:

```
$('#your_form').validate({
    rules : {
        your_date_field_name : { greaterThanToday : true }
    }
});
```